# IntersectionObserver isIntersecting property never is false if threshold greater than 0

Tags: javascript, dom, intersection-observer

If I configure the `threshold` value to anything greater than 0, `isIntersecting` never returns false when the target leaves the viewport.  However, if I leave the default threshold at 0, `isIntersecting` will return false when the target exits the viewport.  See example below and delete `threshold: 1.0`.

https://jsfiddle.net/snewcomer24/get0a4xr/1/

This seems like divergent behavior.  Does anybody have an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is because your observer callback is only called when the element crosses the threshold ratio.

By default the threshold is 0, so the callback is called when the element enters or leaves the viewport. When you change the threshold to 1.0, your callback is *instead* called when the element becomes 100% visible, or stops being 100% visible.

When the element stops being 100%, it will be something like 99% visible, and still have `isIntersecting` as `true`. Then, when the element leaves the viewport, it's not relevant to your observer (since your threshold is not 0), so your callback isn't called again.

If you care about both the element becoming 100% visible and leaving the viewport, you can pass an array as the threshold (like `[0, 1.0]`) and your callback will be called when any of those ratios are crossed.

https://jsfiddle.net/wzst4jx5/12/

An aside: I originally thought `entry.isIntersecting` was just shorthand for `entry.intersectionRatio > 0`. But I've found Chrome (65) can report `isIntersecting` as true, but `intersectionRatio` as 0, when something very slowly enters the viewport.

Comment: I've noticed that in Chrome, in certain cases the `isIntersecting` property may always be `true`, independent of any scrolling. Maybe because I am observing a child element of an SVG.

Comment: I have a horizontal scrolling gallery. The image that is just off the screen to the right has `isIntersecting=true` but also `intersectionRatio=0`. This is consistent behavior and not based on speed of scrolling. The width of the slide is either 100vw or a fixed screen width.

Comment: I'm seeing some very small values like 0.0009 as intersectionRatio, therefore I think 0 is just being rounded down in some cases. But an item can be one pixel off screen and still intersecting!